# Is there an LDAP standard group membership attribute for users?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I'm currently working on an application which uses LDAP as an authentication method. I was wondering if the `LDAP` protocol has a standard membership attribute which would hold the user's group? So far `memberOf` is working in `OpenLDAP` and `Active Direcotry` but not in `Apache DS`. I couldn't find this attribute in the RFCs so I'm kind of confused. Should I be using the `memberOf` attribute or I need to go the old fashion way traversing over all of the groups to find which group has the `member`?

Comment: 'memberOf' is an operational attribute so you won't find it in RFCs. OpenLDAP only has it if you configure it.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this! Are there any other "workarounds" except traversing? I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: @tftd memberOf only holds groups that the user is directly a member of anyway, not groups they are a member of via other group members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the standards, only the member attribute on the group (as used by Microsoft Active Directory) can be "counted" on.

RFC 4519 section 2.17 states:
"The 'member' attribute type contains the distinguished names of objects that are on a list or in a group.  Each name is one value of this multi-valued attribute."

The memberOF (used by Microsoft Active Directory) and groupMberShip (used by eDirectory) are implementation specific attribute added to the user.

The [memberOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (used by Microsoft Active Directory) attribute is controlled by the server and is not modifiable. (flagged as Read Only from LDAP and System-Only in MS speak)

### Beware of MemberOf

Active Directory Groups, by default, only include MemberOf if they have a Group Scope of:

- Universal Group and are in the same AD Forest as the user, or
- Global Group and user are on the same AD DOMAIN (even if in the same AD Forest)
- Domain Local Group only if user is from the same AD DOMAIN of the Domain Controller you are retrieving results from.
- NOT include the user’s primary group (usually Domain Users)
- NOT include Active Directory Groups on external trusted domains.

-jim